# How to convert a String to long in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, long-integer, unix-timestamp

I have a millisecond timestamp that I need to convert from a string to long. JavaScript has a `parseInt` but not a `parseLong`. So how can I do this?

To expand on my question slightly: given that apparently JavaScript doesn't have a long type, how can I do simple arithmetic with longs that are initially expressed as strings? E.g subtract one from the other to get a time delta?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a parseLong because it doesn't have a long.  (Some old-timer may be able to tell you a story about why Javascript never got a long.)

Comment: So it's not possible to do arithmetic with longs in javascript??

Comment: can you give a code example of what you want to do?

Comment: @Russ - your answer below explains it all. thx

Answer (score 133, accepted):

JavaScript has a `Number` type which is a 64 bit floating point number*.

If you're looking to convert a string to a number, use

1. either [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). If using `parseInt`, I'd recommend always passing the radix too.
2. use the Unary `+` operator e.g. `+"123456"`
3. use the `Number` constructor e.g. `var n = Number("12343")`

**there are situations where the number will internally be held as an integer.*

Comment: So, if I wanted to parse the string `"71157133118211271"` to a number/long in Javascript, how would I go about that? Split it into 16-digit strings, parse each of them separately, and concatenate them together?

Comment: @CharlieS You use a library like javascript-bignum (https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) or BigInt.js (http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html) that provides support for large numbers.

Comment: be careful with zero to left side

Answer (score 9):

`BigInt("1274836528318476135")`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646698/base-36-to-bigint