# js parseInt() one off (large number)

Tags: javascript

When I run the following:

```
parseInt('96589218797811259658921879781126'.slice(0, 16), 10);
```

the output is

```
9658921879781124
```

whereas the expected is, as you can see:

```
9658921879781125
```

What is the cause? I understand vaguely in googling around that there are [issues with large numbers](http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) in JS and that this indeed appears to be above that threshold, but I don't know what to do about it, or what is happening in this specific case. Thank you.

Edit: Thanks for the answers, I see that depending on an integer this size is bad news. The reason for using an integer is because I need to increment by one, then compare to the rest of the string. In this case, the first half of the string should equal the second half after incrementing the first half by one. What is an alternative approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: `9658921879781124  > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450012/how-to-convert-a-string-to-long-in-javascript

Comment: Looks like the XY problem, what do you want to do with the number?

Comment: FYI: [`For the next range, from 253 to 254, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for why `9658921879781125` becomes `9658921879781124`.

Comment: Why is this down-voted? I genuinely don't understand

Answer (score 1):

It is not a JavaScript issue.

JavaScript uses the [double-precision 64-bit floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (IEEE 754) to store both integer and rational numbers.

This format allows the exact representation of integer numbers between -2<sup>53</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup> (`-9007199254740992` to `9007199254740992`). Outside this interval, some integer values cannot be represented by this format; they are rounded to the nearest integer value that can be represented. For example, from 2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>54</sup>, everything is multiplied by `2`, so the representable numbers are the even ones.

The JavaScript global object [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) provides the constant [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) that represents the maximum integer value that can be stored by the IEEE 574 format (2<sup>53</sup>-1).

It also provides the method [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) you can use to find out if an integer number can be safely stored by the `Number` JavaScript type.

The number you use (`9658921879781124`) is too large to be stored correctly in JavaScript or any other language that uses the double-precision floating point format to store the numbers.