# Base 36 to BigInt?

Tags: javascript, bigint

Suppose I want to convert a base-36 encoded string to a `BigInt`, I can do this:

```
BigInt(parseInt(x,36))
```

But what if my string exceeds what can [safely fit in a Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)? e.g.

```
parseInt('zzzzzzzzzzzzz',36)
```

Then I start losing precision.

Are there any methods for parsing directly into a `BigInt`?

Comment: At the time of writing, the answer is no: there is no mention of any equivalent of `parseInt` in the [BigInt proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/) (Stage 3 Draft, February 11 2019). The only conversion from a string mentioned in the proposal is the `BigInt()` function itself, but that only covers bases 2, 8, 10 and 16.

Comment: @Thomas https://github.com/tc39/proposal-number-fromstring

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could convert the number to a `bigint` type.

```js
function convert(value, radix) {
    return [...value.toString()]
        .reduce((r, v) => r * BigInt(radix) + BigInt(parseInt(v, radix)), 0n);
}

console.log(convert('zzzzzzzzzzzzz', 36).toString());
```

With greater chunks, like just for example with ten (eleven return a false result).

```js
function convert(value, radix) { // value: string
    var size = 10,
        factor = BigInt(radix ** size),
        i = value.length % size || size,
        parts = [value.slice(0, i)];

    while (i < value.length) parts.push(value.slice(i, i += size));

    return parts.reduce((r, v) => r * factor + BigInt(parseInt(v, radix)), 0n);
}

console.log(convert('zzzzzzzzzzzzz', 36).toString());
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know that the parseInt function can work with radices > 16 too. What about radices > 36? Is this documented somewhere? (Didn't find it on MDN...)

Comment: Never mind my questions. MDN states it accepts radices from 2 to 36. ;)

Comment: for greater radices, you need a custom character set, and an own function.

Comment: I wonder if we can batch this in chunks of 11 chars? (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(36).length`).. err, 10 I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there's a built-in one, but base-X to BigInt is pretty easy to implement:

```js
function parseBigInt(
  numberString,
  keyspace = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
) {
  let result = 0n;
  const keyspaceLength = BigInt(keyspace.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < numberString.length; i++) {
    const value = keyspace.indexOf(numberString[i]);
    if (value === -1) throw new Error("invalid string");
    result = result * keyspaceLength + BigInt(value);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(parseInt("zzzzzzz", 36));
console.log(parseBigInt("zzzzzzz"));
console.log(parseBigInt("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"));
```

outputs

```
78364164095
78364164095n
29098125988731506183153025616435306561535n
```

The default `keyspace` there is equivalent to what `parseInt` with base 36 uses, but should you need something else, the option's there. :)

Comment: This function doesn't produce correct results for any string value ending in `0`?

Comment: This parses numbers incorrectly. `parseBigInt('xyz').toString(36)` returns `zyx`. The problem is that it iterates over the string in reverse, parsing the number in reverse.

Comment: @lusc I'm pretty sure this implementation does what it should – it's iterating in reverse because of the `result = result * number-of-digits + current-digit` operation...

Comment: Have you tried doing `parseBigInt('xyz').toString(36)`? Unless I'm missing something it should not return `zyx`.

Comment: @lusc Huh, yeah. Wonder what I'd been thinking, and wonder how this remained unnoticed for a good four years. Thanks!