# parseInt() - String to Integer and back in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to reverse engineering some Javascript code and recode it in PHP.
There is a String which is "converted" with parseInt(String, 36) to an Integer.
I need a posibility to convert the integer back to the secret String in PHP, without knowing the secret string.

```js
secretCode = "0vo8fz4kvy03";
decode = parseInt(secretCode, 36).toString();
console.log(decode); //= 115802171408044510
```

How i can do that in PHP?
`115802171408044510` back to `0vo8fz4kvy03`

This interger contains some informations:

```
decode="115802171408044510";
storeID = decode.substr(0, 4); // 1158
posID = decode.substr(12, 2); // 04
orderID = decode.substr(14, 2); // 45
day = decode.substr(6, 2); // 17
month = decode.substr(4, 2); // 02
hour = decode.substr(8, 2); // 14
minutes = decode.substr(10, 2); // 08
```

I would like to edit this values above and convert this back to a "secretCode" String.
They are doing exactly this somehow server-side.

Comment: you may have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55646698/1447675), for gerater numbers than are safe integer numbers. why does this question have a [tag:javascript] tag?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but `115802171408044510 = vo8fz4kvxzy` and `0vo8fz4kvy03 = 115802171408044515`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert your javascript encoded number string from base 10 to base 36:

```php
$decode = "115802171408044510";
echo base_convert ( $decode , 10 , 36 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The number overflows the maximum safe integer size, therefore it is impossible to reverse this process (as the number gets rounded to the next safe integer). Therefore the code is broken.

Comment: I added some Informations at the end of the Question, to make it better understandable. So, there is no possibility for me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`You can try.`

```
decode.toString(36)
```

Comment: Tried this already, but that gives me another result.
But altought, i need a possibility to do this in PHP.

console.log(parseInt("0vo8fz4kvy03", 36).toString(36)); //= vo8fz4kvy00

Answer (score 2):

You could take `BigInt` and convert large values to decimal or back to string.

```js
function convertFrom(value, radix) {
    return [...value.toString()]
        .reduce((r, v) => r * BigInt(radix) + BigInt(parseInt(v, radix)), 0n);
}

function convertTo(value, radix) {
    var result = '',
        r = BigInt(radix);
     
    do {
        result = (value % r).toString(36) + result;
        value = value / r;
    } while (value);
    return result;
}

var secretCode = "0vo8fz4kvy03",
    value = convertFrom(secretCode, 36),
    encode = convertTo(value, 36);

console.log(value.toString());
console.log(encode.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method receives an optional argument, which lets you set the base of the result.

So all you need to do is `(+decode).toString(36)`.

```js
secretCode = "0vo8fz4kvy03";
decode = parseInt(secretCode, 36).toString();
console.log(decode); //= 115802171408044510
console.log((+decode).toString(36));
```

Notice that I'm converting your `decode` to a number. This is needed because you converted the result of `parseInt` directly to a string, so you never actually hold the number.

Comment: Tahnks, but that gives me "vo8fz4kvy00" instead of "0vo8fz4kvy03" and i need that in PHP.

Comment: Oh, you're outside the bounds of a JavaScript integer, which is 53-bit. Didn't notice that.

Comment: ...you can use a "big number" library to handle such values.

Answer (score 0):

The `intval` function in PHP is the closest to `parseInt` in Javascript including the support for radix parameter:

```php
$int = intval('9', 36);
```

In Javascript, `parseInt` returns `NaN` for inputs that can not be parsed to integer; but in PHP, `intval` returns `0`.

Look for the details about [intval function in php docs](https://www.php.net/intval).