# Is there a way to convert a string larger than a length of 15 to a number, without rounding?

Tags: javascript, numbers

When converting a large string to a number, I noticed there is round after the 15th digit. Is there a way to convert a string to a number to in JS without rounding, regardless of the length?

```
Number("9223372036854775807")
// returns  9223372036854776000

+"9223372036854775807"
// returns  9223372036854776000

"9223372036854775807"*1
// returns  9223372036854776000
```

Comment: BigInt - though that's not a Number

Comment: use BigInt() option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450012/how-to-convert-a-string-to-long-in-javascript

Comment: `BigInt` is its own type. Is there no way to solve this while keeping the type a `number`? Is this just a short coming of JS?

Comment: @eagercoder I just found the bugnumber js library. Think it will serve your purpose - https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) object which can hold numbers upto `2^53 - 1`.

```
let hugeString = BigInt("9223372036854775807")
console.log(hugeString);
// outputs: 9223372036854775807n
```